# Text Editor with "run button" that does not have public account

Tags: javascript, html, css, editor, chromebook

I am teaching 4th and 5th grade tech to some very bright students and I have found they show more interest in typing while coding as opposed to coding activities like code.org. I am looking for a text editor with a run button so they can see results quickly. I need one for free or one that's not very expensive, and it has to be private. I know repl.it is free, but it's not private, there for not safe for students. Does anyone know of a text editor we can put on chromebooks that hopefully has a run button or can eaily give us a preview of the code? We will be using HTML, CSS, and JS.

Comment: You're coercing children, so I cannot help you.

Comment: What should this run button do? If you're using html, css and js you don't need to compile anything

Comment: Hello and Welcome to SO. Unfortunatly your question does not meet the SO requirements. SO is for specific coding problems not for program recommendations. Since your question is not related to a specific coding issue and also opinion-based it will eb flagged to be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of options. Check out:

1. https://playcode.io/
2. https://jsfiddle.net/
3. https://codepen.io/

Also, there are numerous other options, try to google for "javascript sandbox"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use web page, jsfiddle or codepen,

If you want to use desktop app, vscode with live server extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can never go wrong with [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) :)

---

It has a clean interface and a registration/sign in option to save your work.